# File transfer from pixel 6 / Android 12 to Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, android

I connected my Google Pixel 6, with the new Android 12, with my Ubuntu 20/04 Notebook via USB.

In Files I see the Pixel 6, on the phone. I activated:

- Use USB for "File transfer / Android Auto".

But Files, after trying 20 seconds, tells me 'Unable to access "Pixel 6"'

Sure I can upload e.g. photos to google drive and copy them from there. But I would like to have a direct access to the file system which was no problem at all on my Samsung S9 / Android 8.

As well I tried toggling in between the options and reconnecting which both did not help.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Does PTP (photos) work or shows the same symptom? Have you tried toggling "charging only" and back to MPT (file transfer)?

Comment: Ok, I got a "-1" for this question. Fair enough. But would you at least explain why this question shall be stupid?

Comment: I upvoted it to compensate and I was wondering the same. **It's a perfectly valid on-topic question** and other than the information I asked about in the first comment and, eventually, about whether or not you're using the original cable, there's no much that can be added. Please keep in mind you should [edit] the question to add any new info, corrections or other addendums, not just post it in comments.

Comment: @ChanganAuto no PTP does not work either and shows the same symptom. Toggling or reconnecting does not work either.

Comment: Again, please [edit] the question to add new info. Also, are you using the original cable?

Comment: @changanAuto you are awesome. I needed some time to switch the cable. And I don't think that it's the original cable right now. But you pointed me in the right direction. I switched from a usb-2-to-usb-c cable to a usb-c-to-usb-c cable. (Originally used for the connection to my external, portable monitor) and it solved the problem.
Feel free to post your answer I will choose it as the right one and upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Samsung smartphones and especially new generations with USB-C connectors are quite "picky" about the USB cables for anything else other than just charging. It's often recommended to always use the original cable or other third-party known-good cable.

The cable that was being used, a "USB2.0 - USB-C", doesn't work for file transfer. Replacing it with a direct USB-C cable solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a USB-C to USB-C cable that was originally intended for connecting an external portable monitor.

Perhaps another good solution, in general, is to choose a cable that is designed for fast data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more tests.

Until now every test with a USB2-USB-C failed.

Additionally, if I use my USB-C-Connection which is generally used for loading, although the Pixel is recognized on my Notebook I can't transfer files.

My solution now was to use usb-c-cable from a charger and put then into my second usb-c-input on the notebook to make it work.