# Copying file to an unrooted phone which has a type C usb socket

Tags: usb, phone

I want to copy a .apk file from my Ubuntu 20.04 box to my unrooted phone which has a type C socket. lsusb shows the phone. 'adb devices' shows the phone. I have usb debugging enabled on my phone. How do I see what's on my phone's external sdcard and copy an apk file to it from my Ubuntu box. The usb preferences on my phone's settings are ser for File Transfer.
PS I've developed the app using B4a on my Ubuntu box.

Comment: What kind of phone is this? Do you have a desktop environment? Have you checked the file manager?  You shouldn't need USB debugging to connect your phones and access the file system through your file manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File transfer from pixel 6 / Android 12 to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378047/file-transfer-from-pixel-6-android-12-to-ubuntu)

Comment: Blackberry A80Pro phone. Running Ubuntu 20.04. Nautilus sees the phone but won't copy to it. It's problematical to use WiFi (rather than by when connecting by USB cable) for the phone due to walls.

Comment: Phone is Android 9. BTW I've tried using mtp but it didn't work.